# JSP storing password in session

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, session

This issue has been waked up a lot of times i know, but here's unclear moments for me.

I using JSP with Hibernate and i want to implement user's authentification trough database's functinality - `create user ...` - and login with same approach.
So every my script should know the login and password of current user and the only way i know to do it with sessions like:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
       .configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml")
       .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", session.getAttribute("username"))
       .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", session.getAttribute("password"))
       .buildSessionFactory();
```

Is it seems vulnerable? Why should i avoid the pass storage in session if it executes on server side?

Comment: I got confused with HttpSession for HibernateSession. Why do you want it this way?

Comment: i have multiple index.jsp so the hibernateSession will die after some script's execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes. It definetely seems vulnerable.** You don't encrypt anything, so anybody sniffing your client's HTTP requests could intercept her username/password.

The default method for http authentication mechanisms is creating tokens which are invalidated after some time. This token would be encrypted inside a secure cookie. This way, the user's credentials are transfered over the network only once, preferably through a secure https connection. Then only the token would travel.

Anyway, **you don't have to implement such a mechanism yourself**, and to be more precise **you should not implement such a mechanism yourself**, unless you are very sure of what you are doing.

I would strongly recommend on reading the basics of [securing web applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html). The most common way to implement such a functionality is using [forms based authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bncby/index.html). Depending on your application server, an authentication mechanism would already have been [implemented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html). Check for example [this post](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/01/jdbc-realm-glassfish312-primefaces342.html) regarding forms authentication on jdbc realm using glassfish, or [this post](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/realm-howto.html) referring on the same subject using jboss.

Hope I helped!